# How can I return a value of a JavaScript function, which is called by a HTML button click?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to set the var index if the button is clicked. But I also want to use var index in function2. Is there a way to do this without using a global (f.e. by using return)?

HTML:

```
<button id="edit" onclick="editBox()">Bearbeiten</button>
```

JS:

```
function editBox() {
    var index = $(event.target).parent().attr("id");
}

function function2() {
    //some code...
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `function2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first define a variable out of the scope of functions to then call/assign it.

Here you have a working snippet.

```js
let value;

function func1(id) {
  value = id;
  console.log('clicked', id);
}

function func2() {
  alert(value);
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="func1(this.id)">
 Click me and get the id
</button>

<button id="btn2" onclick="func2()">
 Call second function
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean like that:

```
function editBox() {
    var index = $(event.target).parent().attr("id");
    function2(index);
}

function function2(r) {
    //some code ( r is id now)
}
```

Comment: This will only work if `function2` is called from inside `editBox`.

Comment: i know, but did not specify the way so this is one of the methods

Answer (score 0):

If a variable is declared inside a function, its scope is limited to that function and there is no way to access its value from outside the function.

From [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp):

> Local variables have **Function scope**: They can only be accessed from within the function.

To access the same variable inside the second function as well, it must be declared using the `var` keyword outside of both functions. For example:

```js
var index;

function editBox() {
  index = $(event.target).parent().attr("id");
}

function function2() {
  console.log(index);
}
```

---

The only other possibility is passing the variable `index` to `function2()` as a parameter, but this will only work if `function2()` is called from inside `editBox()`.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: `index` need to exist in a large scope than the editBox scope.

You don't want a global variable, so you can do it creating a "closure". In Javascript, you can do it using a IFFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression). In this way, a number of functions and other piece of code share the same scope, but it still "local", not global.

```js
(function(){

  var index;

  $('#edit').on('click', function editBox(event) {
    index = $(event.target).parent().attr("id");
  });

  function function2() {
    // some code
    console.log(index);
  }
  
  // Other code that can call function2 and use index variable...
  
})();
```

```html
<button id="edit">Bearbeiten</button>
```